# Chrome not honoring filename extension - Mac OS X Monterrey

Tags: macos, google-chrome

When I attempt to save an image in Google Chrome v97.0.4692.99 (recently updated), the file extension is not shown in the save dialogue. If the file is of type JPEG, the extension .jpeg is added to the file, even if the file already has the extension .jpg. I'm using MacOS Monterrey v12.1, recently updated. I know that MacOS hides known file extensions, but I have this behavior disabled in Finder. Safari and Firefox don't have this problem. There is no "save as type" option anywhere in the dialogue. My work computer, which is on Big Sur (v11.6.2) and using Chrome, doesn't have this issue, so I suspect it is related to the Monterrey version. Using other browsers, I have eliminated the possibility that the image doesn't have a correct mime-type. I'm also 99% sure that this is not Chrome serving a .webp request.

Does anyone else have this problem? If it's a bug, who do I report it to?

Steps to recreate:

1. Navigate to an image file
2. Attempt to save the image

Sample URL:
https://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Cute-Red-Bunny.jpg

Results screenshot (compact dialogue shown):

[image: Chrome save dialogue]

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. So darn annoying! Also only started after upgrading to Monterey. This is a known bug apparently: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1281406